# How to useOnPropertyChanged .NET Maui

Tags: c#, xml, maui

I'm learning .NET Maui and I'm having difficulties with PropertyChanged. What I wanted to happen in this code is quite simple: when I add a PDF or a Category, it should update the View and display the new Category or PDF.

**XML**

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="#282828" RowDefinitions="100*, auto">
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
            <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="True">
                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource CategoryLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                            <toolkit:Expander.Content>
                                <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding PDFs}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>

                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEntered="MouseHoverEffect_PointerEntered" />
                                                    <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerExited="MouseHoverEffect_PointerExited" />
                                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                                <Label
                                                    Padding="10"
                                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                    TextColor="#FFF" />
                                            </StackLayout>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </toolkit:Expander.Content>
                        </toolkit:Expander>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,0,10,10"
            BackgroundColor="#FFF"
            Clicked="ShowAddOptions_Clicked"
            CornerRadius="20"
            FontSize="16"
            HeightRequest="40"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Text="+"
            TextColor="#282828"
            WidthRequest="40" />
    </Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoadCategoriesAndPdfs();
        }

        private string _categoriesPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Categories");
        private List<Category> _categories;

        public List<Category> Categories
        {
            get { return _categories; }
            set
            {
                _categories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Categories));
            }
        }

        public async Task AddPdf()
        {
            try
            {
                var PDFs = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
                {
                    FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Pdf
                });

                if (PDFs.Count() != 0)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\")))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\"));

                    List<string> pdfAlreadyExists = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var PDF in PDFs)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\", PDF.FileName)))
                        {
                            pdfAlreadyExists.Add(PDF.FileName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.Copy(PDF.FullPath, Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\", PDF.FileName));
                        }
                    }
                    if (pdfAlreadyExists.Count != 0)
                    {
                        string message = $"The following PDFs already exist: \n\n";
                        foreach (var pdfName in pdfAlreadyExists)
                        {
                            message += $"{pdfName}\n\n";
                        }

                        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, message, "OK");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        public async Task AddCategory()
        {
            try
            {
                string result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Choose a name", "Category Name");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result)))
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, "Category already exists", "Ok");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && !Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        public void LoadCategoriesAndPdfs()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(_categoriesPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_categoriesPath);

            List<Category> categories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_categoriesPath)
                .Select(directory => new Category
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(directory),
                    PDFs = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf")
                    .Select(file => new PDF
                    {
                        Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                        Category = Path.GetFileName(directory),
                        Path = file
                    })
                    .ToList()
                })
                .ToList();

            Categories = categories;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I know that if I call the method LoadCategoriesAndPdfs() inside the AddPDF() and AddCategory() methods, it works, but I wanted to use OnPropertyChanged because I believe it's a good practice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can check this [MVVM Toolkit Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features) to use the MAUI CommunityToolkit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.  This will automatically fire a `CollectionChanged` event when an item is added or removed.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` only applies to changes to individual properties of objects, not to elements of a collection.

Comment: I changed the variable "Categories" and "_categories" to ObservableCollection, made the necessary code changes, but it didn't work. When I add a PDF or Category, it still doesn't function properly. I probably did something wrong.

Comment: you need to be sure your collections are initialized in the constructor.  If you initialize or reassign them later it will break the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install and use the MVVM Community Toolkit, this way the majority of this logic would be autogenerated so you don't have to worry about it... most of the times (nugget packet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/8.2.1?_src=template))

So, your code would look like this:

**ViewModel**

```
public partial class YourViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        LoadCategoriesAndPdfs();
    }

    private string _categoriesPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Categories");
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

    [RelayCommand] //<- If i'm understading correctly, those are methods that you are calling in the xaml, so you can use the command property of the button, instead of using the event clicked and manage it on code behind.
    async Task AddPdf()
    {
        try
        {
            var PDFs = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
            {
                FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Pdf
            });

            if (PDFs.Count() != 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\")))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\"));

                List<string> pdfAlreadyExists = new List<string>();

                foreach (var PDF in PDFs)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\", PDF.FileName)))
                    {
                        pdfAlreadyExists.Add(PDF.FileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Copy(PDF.FullPath, Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, "Others\\", PDF.FileName));
                    }
                }
                if (pdfAlreadyExists.Count != 0)
                {
                    string message = $"The following PDFs already exist: \n\n";
                    foreach (var pdfName in pdfAlreadyExists)
                    {
                        message += $"{pdfName}\n\n";
                    }

                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, message, "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    async Task AddCategory()
    {
        try
        {
            string result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Choose a name", "Category Name");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result)))
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, "Category already exists", "Ok");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && !Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_categoriesPath, result));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(null, ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
    //If this method is called only inside here, i would make it private
    private void LoadCategoriesAndPdfs()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_categoriesPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_categoriesPath);

        List<Category> categories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_categoriesPath)
            .Select(directory => new Category
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(directory),
                PDFs = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf")
                .Select(file => new PDF
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    Category = Path.GetFileName(directory),
                    Path = file
                })
                .ToList()
            })
            .ToList();

        //Categories = categories; you know have to do like this to "copy" the list to the observable collection
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            Categories.Add(category);
        }
        //Do do proper checks. (list empty/null and so on)
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="#282828" RowDefinitions="100*, auto">
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
        <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource CategoryLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                        <toolkit:Expander.Content>
                            <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding PDFs}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEntered="MouseHoverEffect_PointerEntered" />
                                                <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerExited="MouseHoverEffect_PointerExited" />
                                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                            <Label
                                                Padding="10"
                                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                TextColor="#FFF" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Content>
                    </toolkit:Expander>

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,0,10,10"
        BackgroundColor="#FFF"
        Command="{Binding AddCategoryCommand}" <!-- or the other command, i don't know which one are you calling -->
        CornerRadius="20"
        FontSize="16"
        HeightRequest="40"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        Text="+"
        TextColor="#282828"
        WidthRequest="40" />
</Grid>
```

Hope this will help you, if you have any doubts, feel free to comment the answer :)

Comment: best practice would be to create a BaseViewModel class that inherits from ObservableObject, and then YourViewModel would inherit from it. This way, each ViewModel would inherit from BaseViewModel and not directly from ObservableObject. But is up to you, is just to make it cleaner i would say